# Scrapy - How to have a custom path for multiple file URLs in one item when uploading to S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, scrapy

From my understanding is that in order for me to use Files Pipeline I need to include these to my settings.py:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'access key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= 'secret'
FILES_STORE = 's3://bucket／'
```

And I need to add these to my Item object

```
file_urls = scrapy.Field()
files = scrapy.Field()
```

and the result would be something like this:

```
{'file_urls': ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png',
                'https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAGkl.png'],
 'files': [{'checksum': 'b0974ea6c88740bed353206b279e0827',
             'path': 'full/762f5682798c5854833316fa171c71166e284630.jpg',
             'url': 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png'},
            {'checksum': '9a42f7bd1dc45840312fd49cd08e6a5c',
             'path': 'full/615eabb7b61e79b96ea1ddb34a2ef55c8e0f7ec3.jpg',
             'url': 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAGkl.png'}]}
```

From my understanding, the Files Pipeline will automatically populate the images field.

My question here is that is there anyway for me to change the 'path' value in the images field? In my case I want to store many different items under a different sub-directory each, and they are all scraped by the same spider, is there a way that I can do this, like creating and extending my own Files pipeline for example? If so, How would I approach this?

Also I need to mention that I pass 2 different URLs with 1 item and I would like them to be in different directories

(also yes I know they are images, I'm just using it as en example because they were the ones I found first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, if you look at the source code for the scrapy files pipeline [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py)

you will see that it has methods which you can override, one of them is the `file_path` method, which you override by adding it to your pipeline class like so

```
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
    # start of deprecation warning block (can be removed in the future)
        def _warn():
            from scrapy.exceptions import ScrapyDeprecationWarning
            import warnings
            warnings.warn('FilesPipeline.file_key(url) method is deprecated,\
            please use file_path(request, response=None, info=None) instead',
                      category=ScrapyDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=1)

    # check if called from file_key with url as first argument
    if not isinstance(request, Request):
        _warn()
        url = request
    else:
        url = request.url

    # detect if file_key() method has been overridden
    if not hasattr(self.file_key, '_base'):
        _warn()
        return self.file_key(url)
    # end of deprecation warning block

    # Modify the file path HERE to your own custom path 
    filename = request.meta['filename']
    media_ext = 'jpg'
    return '%s/%s/%s.%s' % \
        (request.meta['image_category'],
            request.meta['image_month'],
            filename, media_ext)
```

The result of this would be a directory like:

```
vehicles/june/toyota.jpg

Where vehicles is the image_category, june is image_month and toyota is the filename
```

What this would do is if you look at the last few lines of the code [which is the only code I have added the rest is as the method is from the Scrapy source code]

```
    # Modify the file path HERE to your own custom path 
    filename = request.meta['filename']
    media_ext = 'jpg'
    return '%s/%s/%s.%s' % \
        (request.meta['image_category'],
            request.meta['image_month'],
            filename, media_ext)
```

is return a custom path
now this path depends on a few things, on the spider you can collect image meta fields like filename for image name, image category and anything else like date the image was take and use it in the pipeline to create a custom directory

Comment: great! this worked like a charm. Do you know if I can get away with removing the depreciation warning block?

Comment: @EdwardFu I am not sure I have not tried it yet, though it doesn't hurt to try

Comment: Actually my files in my Item isn't being populated automatically by my files pipeline after I overwrote that function, do you know why?

Comment: I am not really sure. There is the `item_completed` method, it is called after an item is done, you can use it to debug whatever is going on, but for my case everything seems to work fine and I have written a couple of scrappers in this manner

Comment: sorry for bothering you but I figured it out, it was something on my end